# Text-Align not working after I had one column

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, text-align

In "My Skills" section, I'd like to align the skill titles on the right, next to the progression bar, like in the [Original Theme](http://webthemez.com/demo/neu-free-web-designer-profile-responsive-web-template/).

But as soon as I had a column, the text-align stops working.

Here's the Codepen : http://codepen.io/zaky/pen/KdXGEj/

HTML

```
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-MfvZlkHCEqatNoGiOXveE8FIwMzZg4W85qfrfIFBfYc= sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Heading -->
  <h2>Skills</h2>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
  </div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h2>One <strong>Skills</strong></h2>
    <p class="mrgBtm20">
      Lorem Ipsum              
    </p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 skilltitle">Axure</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 skilltitle">Photoshop</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 skilltitle">Analytics</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>     
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h2>Two <strong>Skills</strong></h2>
    <p class="mrgBtm20">
      Lorem Ipsum
    </p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 skilltitle">HTML5</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 90%;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 skilltitle">CSS3</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 90%;">
            <span class="sr-only">80% Complete</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 skilltitle">jQuery</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <h2>Three <strong>Skills</strong></h2>
    <p class="mrgBtm20">
      Lorem Ipsum 
    </p>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 skilltitle">Intelligence</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 90%;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 skilltitle">Pitching</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="80" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 skilltitle">Monetizing</div>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 75%;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>        
</body>
```

CSS

```
/*Skills*/
.skilltitle {
text-align: right;
font-family : 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight : 700;

}
.progress {
border-radius: 0px;
height: 15px;
margin-top: 5px;
background-color: #D6D6D6;
margin-left : 20px;
}
.progress .progress-bar {
background-color: #30486A;
}
/*Skills*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your theme is overwriting the `text-align: right;` on line 1023 in your css (in the media query). So whenever your browser width is below 768px, the text will align to the left.

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
   .skilltitle {
       text-align: left;
   }
}
```

Remove the `.skilltitle { text-align: left; }` in the media query, so it doesn't overwrite the `text-align: right;` that you declared earlier in your css. Now your text should be aligned right when you have one column.

Answer (score 0):

```
Updated 

1. add nopadding class beside col-md-8 like below markup for all skills and add below css to override the default column padding.

.nopadding {
   padding: 0 !important;
   margin: 0 !important;
}

Remove the padding of progress class:
.progress {

    /* margin-left: 20px; */ remove this and check
}


    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-md-8 nopadding">
        <div class="progress">
          <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 80%;">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
     <div class="col-md-2 skilltitle">Photoshop</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I want the text to stay at the left of the progress bar, but sticked to it, as in the original theme's skills section.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it doesn't work. The text remains left-aligned and now overlaid by the progress bar, as you can see on this screenshot : http://hpics.li/ac2b05b